# Adding rows to a Pandas dataframe based on a list in a column (and vice versa)

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this dataframe:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],['A','B'],[['C','D'],'E']],columns=list('AB'))
        A  B
0       1  2
1       A  B
2  [C, D]  E
```

... that I want to transform in ...

```
        A  B
0       1  2
1       A  B
2       C  E
3       D  E
```

... adding a row for each value contained in column A if it's a list.

Which is the most pythonic way?

And vice versa, if I want to group by a column (let's say B) and have in column A a list of the grouped values? (so the opposite that the example above)

Thanks in advance,

Gianluca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed dataframe - `int` with `str` and `list` values (very problematic because many functions raise errors), so first convert all numeric to `str` by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) and mask is by  [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` which convert non numeric to `NaN`:

```
dfx.A = dfx.A.where(pd.to_numeric(dfx.A, errors='coerce').isnull(), dfx.A.astype(str))
print (dfx)
        A  B
0       1  2
1       A  B
2  [C, D]  E
```

and then create new `DataFrame` by [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and flat values of `lists` by `chain.from_iterable`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "B": np.repeat(dfx.B.values, dfx.A.str.len()),
        "A": list(chain.from_iterable(dfx.A))})
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  A  B
2  C  E
3  D  E
```

---

Pure pandas solution convert column `A` to `list` and then create new [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html). Then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) original column `A` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)ed `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dfx.A.values.tolist(), index = dfx.index)
df = dfx.drop('A', axis=1).join(df.stack().rename('A')
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))[['A','B']]
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  A  B
2  C  E
2  D  E
```

---

If need `lists` use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `apply` [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print (df.groupby('B')['A'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index())
   B       A
0  2     [1]
1  B     [A]
2  E  [C, D]
```

but if need `list` only if `length` of values is more as `1` is necessary `if..else`:

```
print (df.groupby('B')['A'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x.values[0])
         .reset_index())
   B       A
0  2       1
1  B       A
2  E  [C, D]
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks

Comment: The solution unfortunately doesn't work if I have string with more than one character in A column, es ['HOME','B','C] because it splits the result in [H,O,M,E,B,C]. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I test first numpy solution and it works nice, in second solution is necessary change `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dfx.A.values.tolist(), index = dfx.index)` to `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dfx.A.values.tolist())`.

Comment: I test it with `dfx = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],['A','B'],[['HOME','C','D'],'E']],columns=list('AB'))`